# how to use settimeout, to remove dynamically appended elements according to their append time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web, settimeout

I need help regarding `settimeout` function.
I made a little plugin, that append 'li' based on specifix parameter.

Like

```
div ({'div':'noo','auto':'true','pos':'top','txt':'hello'});

function div(obj) {
    obj.div;
    obj.auto;
    obj.pos;
    obj.txt;
    obj.time;
    if(obj.pos == 'top') {
        $('<ul id="top"></ul>').appendTo('body');
    }
    if(obj.pos == 'bottom') {
        $('<ul id="bottom"></ul>').appendTo('body');
        $(obj.div).append('<li data-name="' + $.now() + '">' + obj.txt + '</li>');
        if(!obj.time) {
            obj.time = 6000;
        }
        if(obj.auto == 'true') {
            setTimeout(function () {
                $(obj.div + ' li').fadeOut();
            }, obj.time);
        }
    }
}
```

Now, the problem with this code is, if I append a li after few seconds `setTimeout (function (){div ({'div':'bottom','auto':'true','pos':'bottom'});}, 3000);`, than both LIs fadeout at same time (`obj.time`).

I want that, all appended LIs must complete their respective `obj.time` before fadeout.

I also tried to add attr "data-name" on all appended LIs with current time, but dont know how to store all data-name and retrive then into setTimeout function.

Sorry for typo mistakes

Comment: Did you change your code in order to paste it here? Javascript is case sensitive...

Comment: Your code doesn't look right, there are syntax issues. Also `obj.div; obj.auto...` does nothing useful. And why `'true'` and not `true`?

Comment: @jonathan : typo mistakes sir :)

Comment: @elclanrs: I tried true, instead of 'true' but it doesnt work for me.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript is case sensitive so avoid using If instead of if, Function instead of function and SetTimeout instead of setTimeout first.

Comment: sorry dear, its typo mistake.